lazy-loading in Angular Material Table
I am using
 "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7", "@angular/common": "6.1.0", "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0", "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
and I need to implement virtual scrolling or lazy loading in an Angular Material table (with sticky header, sorting, filtering). However, the version of Angular CDK I'm using does not support cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport or ng-table-virtual-scroll.
Are there any alternative approaches or techniques to achieve virtual scrolling or lazy loading for large datasets in an Angular Material table (without using pagination) with this limitation? I'm looking for solutions that do not rely on external libraries.
Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
ps: when I'm trying to import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling'; I'm getting this error "Module '"@angular/cdk/scrolling"' has no exported member 'ScrollingModule'"
